# Reserved Symbol (&, /, etc) in URL Sharepoint Rest Query - Bad Request

Tags: c#, sharepoint, rest, odata

One problem I have been facing off and on for the past few weeks was trying to search SharePoint for a list item value and kept getting bad request error. I had two symbols causing problems, one was that I could not search for something with anh & symbol, and the other was a / (forward slash).

My code looked like:

```
ServiceContext context = new ServiceContext(new Uri("http://URL/_vti_bin/listdata.svc"));
    context.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    var requestType = (System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery<ListTypeValue>)context.ListType
        .Where(v => v.Value.Equals(search));
```

After searching the internet, nothing valid came back besides saying change IIS settings, or convert it to ASCII Html value (NOTE: converting & to %27 still causes bad request error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I found this article](http://developer.netflix.com/forum/read/74789) and it gave me an idea.  I was going to try and use HEX, but since I am using a web service, I couldn't figure anything out. Finally I thought, hey, someone stated how they used substringof, why not try startswith!

Finally! A solution to this problem.

```
INVALID:
http://URL/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/ListType('Search & Stuff')

VALID:
http://URL/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/ListType() $filter=startswith(Value,'Search & Stuff')
```

I took it a step further since this could potentially return not what I wanted. I added length is equal to the strings length and it is working perfectly!

My C# Code looks like this now:

```
ServiceContext context = new ServiceContext(new Uri("http://URL/_vti_bin/listdata.svc"));
context.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
var requestType = (System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery<ListTypeValue>)context.ListType
    .Where(v => v.Value.StartsWith(search) && v.Value.Length == search.Length);
```

Hopefully this helps someone else out and saves some hair pulling!

---

### **UPDATE:**

After getting replies from people, I found a better way to do this. Instead of the standard LINQ method of querying, there is another option. [See MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd673933.aspx)

```
System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery<ListTypeValue> lobtest = context.ListType
    .AddQueryOption("$filter", "(Value eq '" + CleanString(search) + "')");
```

Now I will implement [link posted from Mark Stafford](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/peter_qian/archive/2010/05/25/using-wcf-data-service-with-restricted-characrters-as-keys.aspx) and parse out reserved characters.

Comment: Why not just compare for equality? $filter=(Value eq 'Search & Stuff')

Comment: Wasn't sure that was possible after seeing how it was automatically formatted from Linq. Using v.Value.Equals or v.Value == both are formatted using the default.

Comment: LINQ will translate a single Where condition with equality comparison on a key property using the ~/Set(key) syntax. This is done so that it's possible to express navigations in LINQ (like ~/Set(key)/NavProperty). If the condition is more complicated it will fall back to generate the $filter.

Comment: Well after some more reason, I feel upon another way of doing the query. Thanks for your reply made me think of the more clean solution! Check my edit out.

Answer (score 2):

I would really not recommend using the combination of StartsWith and Length - performance could become a real issue in that case. Assuming you need a string key and that you want your keys to be able to contain special characters, Peter Qian has blogged about the best recommendation we can give. (This behavior actually comes from a combination of IIS and the .NET stack.)

Check out http://blogs.msdn.com/b/peter_qian/archive/2010/05/25/using-wcf-data-service-with-restricted-characrters-as-keys.aspx for more details, but your problem should be solved by turning off ASP.NET request filtering. Note that this has non-trivial security risks. Peter points out some of them, and security filtering tools like asafaweb.com will complain about this solution.

Long story short: if you can use integers or avoid the restricted characters in keys, your Web application will be more secure.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I had looked over this website and decided not to use it for a few reasons. For one, I was not sure if this was possible for a SharePoint web service. I figured this was configured automatically by SharePoint and on top of that thought it may be too difficult to even get into that portion of code if it were possible. Second, I didn't feel like pleading my case to make the service even a hair less secure.